# Polars Convert Back From Dummies

Tags: python, python-polars

In pandas I can use the [`from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html) method to reverse one-hot encoding. There doesn't seem to be a built in method for this in polars. Here is a basic example:

```
pl.DataFrame({
  "col1_hi": [0,0,0,1,1],
  "col1_med": [0,0,1,0,0],
  "col1_lo": [1,1,0,0,0],
  "col2_yes": [1,1,0,1,0],
  "col2_no": [0,0,1,0,1],
})

┌─────────┬──────────┬─────────┬──────────┬─────────┐
│ col1_hi ┆ col1_med ┆ col1_lo ┆ col2_yes ┆ col2_no │
│ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64      ┆ i64     ┆ i64      ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪══════════╪═════════╪══════════╪═════════╡
│ 0       ┆ 0        ┆ 1       ┆ 1        ┆ 0       │
│ 0       ┆ 0        ┆ 1       ┆ 1        ┆ 0       │
│ 0       ┆ 1        ┆ 0       ┆ 0        ┆ 1       │
│ 1       ┆ 0        ┆ 0       ┆ 1        ┆ 0       │
│ 1       ┆ 0        ┆ 0       ┆ 0        ┆ 1       │
└─────────┴──────────┴─────────┴──────────┴─────────┘
```

Reversing the [`to_dummies`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.to_dummies.html#polars.DataFrame.to_dummies) operation should result in something like this:

```
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ lo   ┆ yes  │
│ lo   ┆ yes  │
│ med  ┆ no   │
│ hi   ┆ yes  │
│ hi   ┆ no   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

My first thought was to use a pivot. How could I go about implementing this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could utilize [`pl.coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html)

```
(df
 .with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col(col) == 1)
      .then(pl.lit(col).str.extract(r"([^_]+$)"))
      .alias(col) 
    for col in df.columns)
 .select(
    pl.coalesce(pl.col(f"^{prefix}_.+$")).alias(prefix) 
    for prefix in dict.fromkeys(
       col.rsplit("_", maxsplit=1)[0]
       for col in df.columns
    )
))
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ lo   ┆ yes  │
│ lo   ┆ yes  │
│ med  ┆ no   │
│ hi   ┆ yes  │
│ hi   ┆ no   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

**Update:** [@Rodalm's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75953962/) is much neater:

```
def from_dummies(df, separator="_"):
    col_exprs = {}
    
    for col in df.columns:
        name, value = col.rsplit(separator, maxsplit=1)
        expr = pl.when(pl.col(col) == 1).then(value) 
        col_exprs.setdefault(name, []).append(expr)

    return df.select(
        pl.coalesce(exprs) # keep the first non-null expression value by row
          .alias(name)
        for name, exprs in col_exprs.items()
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to [@jqurious's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75949425/17120692) using [`pl.coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
  "col1_hi": [0,0,0,1,1],
  "col1_med": [0,0,1,0,0],
  "col1_lo": [1,1,0,0,0],
  "col2_yes": [1,1,0,1,0],
  "col2_no": [0,0,1,0,1],
})

def from_dummies(df, sep="_"):

    col_exprs = defaultdict(list)
    for col in df.columns:
        name, value = col.split(sep)
        expr = pl.when(pl.col(col) == 1).then(value) # null otherwise
        col_exprs[name].append(expr)

    res = df.select(**{
        name: pl.coalesce(exprs) # keep the first non-null expression value by row
        for name, exprs in col_exprs.items()
    })
    return res
```

Or generalizing [@warwick12's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75949209/17120692) using multiple *when* and *thens* chained:

```py
def from_dummies(df, sep="_"):

    col_exprs = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        name, value = col.split(sep)
        if name not in col_exprs:
            col_exprs[name] = pl.when(pl.col(col) == 1).then(value)
        else:
            col_exprs[name] = col_exprs[name].when(pl.col(col) == 1).then(value)
 
    return df.select(**col_exprs)
```

Output:

```py
>>> from_dummies(df)

shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ lo   ┆ yes  │
│ lo   ┆ yes  │
│ med  ┆ no   │
│ hi   ┆ yes  │
│ hi   ┆ no   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Ah I see, building a dict when performing the split, how did I miss that. A much neater solution - thank you.

Comment: @jqurious Using `pl.colaesce` + `pl.when` was very clever of you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pl.when(), pl.col() and pl.lit() methods to convert a polars DataFrame with dummy variables back to the original format. This map's each column's dummies back to their original values.

```
import polars as pl

# Create dummy variable DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "col1_hi": [0,0,0,1,1],
    "col1_med": [0,0,1,0,0],
    "col1_lo": [1,1,0,0,0],
    "col2_yes": [1,1,0,1,0],
    "col2_no": [0,0,1,0,1],
})

# Map dummies back to original values
df = df.select([
    pl.when(pl.col("col1_hi") == 1).then(pl.lit("hi"))
    .when(pl.col("col1_med") == 1).then(pl.lit("med")).otherwise("lo").alias("col1"),
    pl.when(pl.col("col2_yes") == 1).then(pl.lit("yes")).otherwise("no").alias("col2")
])

# Display original DataFrame
print(df)
```

Output:

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ lo   ┆ yes  │
│ lo   ┆ yes  │
│ med  ┆ no   │
│ hi   ┆ yes  │
│ hi   ┆ no   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Gets the job done but would be very tedious with many dummy columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a melt/split/filter/pivot like this:

```
df \
    .with_row_count("i") \
    .melt('i') \
    .with_columns(pl.col('variable').str.split('_')) \
    .with_columns(col=pl.col('variable').arr.first(), val=pl.col('variable').arr.last()) \
    .filter(pl.col('value')==1) \
    .pivot('val','i','col') \
    .sort('i').drop('i')
```